# max-width css grid container not taking up 100% of parent container

Tags: css, css-grid, styled-components

I am trying out `css-grid` but I am having some trouble with content taking up 100% of parent container.  I am absolutely lost.  I have a `max-width: 1200px` on the content in my `layouts/index.js` file.  I then call `grid-template-columns: 1fr` in the child Component.  The child component `background-image` does not take up `1200px` but rather `423px`.  The image is 2600px wide.  I thought `1fr` would take up all the space of the max-width content container.  What am I missing?

`layouts/index.js`

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  background: red;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
`;

const Content = styled.div`
  max-width: 1200px;
  background: pink;
  padding-top: 2rem;
  ${media.desktop`padding: 2rem ;`}
  ${media.tablet`padding: 2.4rem;`}
  ${media.phone`padding: 1.2rem;`}
  margin: 0 auto;
`;

const LayoutWrapper = ({ children }) => (
  <Wrapper>
    <Helmet
      title="Fouts Tax Service"
      meta={[
        { name: 'description', content: 'A tax service in Anderson, Indiana run by Jerry Fouts' },
        { name: 'keywords', content: 'tax, anderson, 46011, indiana, service, fouts,' },
      ]}
    />
    <ResponsiveHeader/>
    <Content>
      {children()}
    </Content>
    <Footer/>
  </Wrapper>
);
```

`pages/index.js`

```js
import HeroImg from '../images/taxes.jpg'

const Grid = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  border: 2px solid black;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  align-content: center;
`;

const Showcase = styled.div`
  background-image: url(${HeroImg});
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #a7a7a7;
  background-blend-mode: color-burn;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 4rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: start;

class IndexPage extends Component {

render() {
    return (
      <Grid>
        <Showcase>
          <h1>Fouts Tax Service</h1>
          <h3>Year round tax service</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing.</p>
        </Showcase>
      </Grid>
    )

  }
}
```

Here is a picture of what I am talking about.
[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Comment: It would be useful if your code could reproduce the problem. Currently, your code doesn't match the image you posted.

Comment: maybe remove `margin: 0 auto;` and use the alignment properties from grid to align the items. You could also explicit set `width: 100%` to take full available width.

Comment: Okay I will add all the code

Comment: `Kunukn` margin:0 auto was what was causing problems.  I can't believe I didn't think of that.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try adding min-width: 0; to grid-items.

Comment: I had the same problem, and the `min-width: 0` did fix my problem. Could you elaborate the reason why it works?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error while using the following

```html
<grid-element>
  <angular-component>
   <swiper>
    <!-- ... -->
      <img src="yourImage.jpg">
    <!-- ... -->
   </swiper>
  </angular-component>
</grid-element>
```

I tried the answer from @janisKonutis and it worked

```
grid-element { 
  display: grid
  > * {
    min-width: 0; // <-- This did fix the problem
  }
}
```

But I was interested to know why. the nice css-tricks.com propose [a bunch of possible fixes](https://css-tricks.com/preventing-a-grid-blowout/)

#### Explanation from [Chris Coyier](https://css-tricks.com/preventing-a-grid-blowout/)

> I can’t promise I’m explaining this 100% accurately, but the way I understand it, the minimum width of a grid column is auto. (The same is true for flex items, by the way.)

> And since auto is entirely based on content, we can say it is “indefinitely” sized, its dimensions flex. If we were to put an explicit width on the column, like 50% or 400px, then we would say it is “definitely” sized.

> To apply our fix, we need to make sure that there is the column has a definite minimum width instead of auto.